# Upload Googlesheet Data to Google Cloud service and then Analyse with CloudSQL

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

This question is edited to make requirements clearer:

I am involved with a charity with multiple location. It provides low cost medicines. Current the transaction data - sale purchases is stored in Googlesheets in each location. As it grows it is becoming a pain to analyse one by one.

The data is structured. Each Table/Tab has defined fields. Each location has identical structure and I can easily have a unique ID.

I have also experimented with local Postgresql database. Data is in standard Table format - each location has identical format.

As each shop is selling each day, each day there are new transactions.

I need a simple way of collecting all this information in **one place** in the cloud so that I can analyse the data using SQL type queries without having to manually get it from each location each day. In total there are some 2000 new transactions in a day that need to be added to database.

One logical solution would be for each local postgresql database to send new data to a cloud master postgresql database - using WAL? Local databases dont have 24x7 internet access - net is patchy. Charity is in India. I am in UK.

Ideally I need a solution where when the local computer finds net, it transmits the new transactions to the cloud database.

Comment: If you want to perform analytics, why using CLoud SQL database and not an analytics database? Do you have a strong requirement on Cloud SQL? What will you do with the data and after your analysis done?

Comment: Guillaume - its because I dont know what I am talking about but willing to learn. What I am looking to do is to 1. centralise all my data in one place from various locations. 2. To analyse that data using SQL type queries - for example what order to place for each location. Hope its clearer?

Answer (score 0):

```
"""Import these modules"""
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

"""Import the sheet"""
scope = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("Path to your 
credentials.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("Your sheet").sheet1

"""The cell on Top of a column is for the title of the column """
sheet.updatecell(1, 1, "Sales")

"""Reading the file where the data is stored and writing it in the sheet"""
with open("Path to the file where the sales are stored", "r") as l:
    
    data = l.readlines()

    for e, i in enumerate(data):

        i = i[:-1]
        sheet.updatecell(len(e+2), 1, i)
```

I hope this helps, I can't do more since I don't know how the data is stored and organized.

Comment: Tirterra - thanks for above. I am trying to get my head around it. It is copying data from many googlesheets into a single one?